# JavaScript check if string contains any of the words from regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if a string contains any of these words:

```
AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University
```

My current code:

```
var acceptedwords = '/AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University/g'
var str = 'Hello AB';

var matchAccepted = str.match(acceptedwords);
console.log(matchAccepted);

if (matchAccepted !== null) { // Contains the accepted word
    console.log("Contains accepted word: " + str);          

} else {
    console.log("Does not contain accepted word: " + str);

}
```

But for some strange reason this does not match.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `new RegExp('AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University', 'g')` or `/AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University/g` but not a combination of the two :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's not the right way to define a literal [regular expression in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Change

```
var acceptedwords = '/AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University/g'
```

to

```
var acceptedwords = /AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University/;
```

You might notice I removed the g flag : it's useless as you only want to know if there's one match, you don't want to get them all. You don't even have to use `match` here, you could use `test` :

```
var str = 'Hello AB';
if (/AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University/.test(str)) { // Contains the accepted word
    console.log("Contains accepted word: " + str);          
} else {
    console.log("Does not contain accepted word: " + str);
}
```

If you want to build a regex with strings, assuming none of them contains any special character, you could do

```
var words = ['AB','AG', ...
var regex = new RegExp(words.join('|'));
```

If your names may contain special characters, you'll have to use a [function to escape them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).

If you want your words to not be parts of other words (meaning you don't want to match "ABC") then you should check for words boundaries :

```
regex = new RegExp(words.map(function(w){ return '\\b'+w+'\\b' }).join('|'),'g');
```

Comment: could I somehow insert a string between / myVarHere / g ?

Comment: @Alosyius See the [`var regex = RegExp('AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University', 'g');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor.

Comment: @Alosyius: [`[javascript] variable in regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+variable+in+regex)

Comment: Awesome! Accepting asap :)

Comment: @dystroy Would the accepted words not need to be surrounded by word boundaries, `\b` otherwise you could get matches when the accepted words appear within other words. See here: http://regex101.com/r/zS8dT9

Comment: @garyh depends on the goal but yes, that's an interesting comment. Edited